# How to do ajax call and php through submit button without form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, grid, submit

In my javascript there have treeview with checkboxes which is in kendo grid. Outside of grid, there is one button submit that supposed to fetch id that selected checkboxes into database. Anyone know how to do it in correct way?
Here more clearly: https://dojo.telerik.com/IYEvALiY/6

> HTML for button

```
<button id="primaryTextButton" value="submit" class="k-primary" style="float:right; padding: 5px 20px; border-radius: 4px;">Submit</button>
```

> JAVASCRIPT for Ajax

```js
var grid;

$(document).ready(function() {
  dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: "./getTest.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: function() {
          return {
            method: "getTemplate",
            positionTemplateID: document.getElementById('positionTemplateID').value,
            //  hrsPositionID: dropdownlist.value(),
          }
        }
      },

      template: {
        url: "./getTest.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: function() {
          return {
            method: "getTemplate",
            employeeID: document.getElementById('employeeID').value,
            propertyID: document.getElementById('propertyID').value,
          }
        },
        complete: function(e) {
          $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        }
      },
    },
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "positionTemplateID",
      }
    },

  });
```

> PHP for database that supposed Ajax call it insert into database

```
function getTemplate() {
global $ehorsObj;
$positionTemplateID = (isset($_POST['positionTemplateID']) ? $_POST['positionTemplateID'] : '');
$hrsPositionID      = (isset($_POST['hrsPositionID']) ? $_POST['hrsPositionID'] : '');
$programID          = (isset($_POST['programID']) ? $_POST['programID'] : '');
$propertyID         = (isset($_POST['propertyID']) ? $_POST['propertyID'] : '');
$employeeID         = (isset($_POST['employeeID']));
```

Comment: Wrap ajax in a function and use the on click `$("primaryTextButton").on("click",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); callPhp() });`

Comment: Can you show some demo or sample coding? Because i'm a little bit confused right now especially for PHP database.

Comment: Please split the question into a jQUery and a PHP one. Now you are not getting the full answers. The jQuery is really trivial

Comment: Alrights, thank you for tell me.